# Javascript Exit Full Screen Speed

Tags: javascript, animation

I am developing an educational web app that enteres/exits full screen to remove distractions from students when they are studying.  The enter/exit full screen animation speed is slow and doesn't look great and doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

i.e. Calling these:

```
    document.exitFullscreen();
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    document.msExitFullscreen();
```

Is there a way to tell the browser to just exit full screen without a lengthy animation? Or is this OS dependent? (I've tried googling this and haven't found anything much useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be OS dependent, [testing this demo](https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/hmqsF) on Big Sur and latest Chrome, there's a lengthy animation. Enabling `Accessibility-Display-Reduce motion` from System Preferences shorten the transition. On Windows 10 there's no animation at all on Chrome, that's with all Animate options enabled on Performance Options.

Comment: Thanks Martheen. I believe this is correct, but I'll hold off on the answer just in case someone knows a secret trick 